# To store a date in mySQL as dd/MM/yyyy format through Netbeans, but mySQL generally takes yyyy/MM/dd

Tags: java, swing

I entered the following codes. my goal is to store a date in mySQL as dd/MM/yyyy format. But mySQL generally takes yyyy/MM/dd.

```
    String d=(((JTextField)jDateChooser1.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText()); 
    Statement stmt = db.conn.createStatement(); 
    String sql = "insert into diag.current " +     
                 "values'"+col1+"','"+col2+"','"+java.sql.Date.valueOf(d)+"','"+col4+"')";    
    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

I right clicked on the jDateChooser1 and clicked on Customized code, and entered :

```
jDateChooser1= new com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser("dd/MM/yyyy","##/##/####",'_');
```

Now please let me know where i am making the mistake. I will be grateful if someone solves this. Thanks in Advance. I hope i portrayed clearly...

Comment: Could your print String d?

Comment: `Date` should be stored using `java.sql.Date` in the database, then the format is irrelevant.  You may need to verify that the column type is actually capable of storing `Date` values.  It would, also, strongly recommend that you use `PreparedStatement`s when dealing with the database

Comment: yea i can print String d, but i can't store it in database....

Comment: i already used java.sql.Date in the database, as well as preparedStatement. And column type is Date for sure...

Comment: What is the value of the String d ? And in what way isn't it working? Do you get an error on insert? Does it store the data in the database?

Comment: No, you're not using a PreparedStatement. Read your own code. There is no PreparedStatement in there. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: i haven't given the complete code, which is not necessary right now. I just need to know how to save a different format in SQL database, and for conclusion i have read my codes.

Comment: the value of the string is user given, it shows like this, 28/4/2013.

Comment: and i want to store date like this, 28/4/2013, into a database, so please somebody help me.

Comment: The answer is to use a prepared statement which allows setting a java.sql.Date as parameter, which makes the format completely irrelevant. If you ask a question, consider the answers that you receive, otherwise, it's useless. Stop using non-prepared statement and string concatenation. Use prepared statements.

Comment: I have given the complete query what i want, can anyone deliver the complete answer with complete codes...

Comment: There is a complete code example in the tutorial I linked to, along with detailed and clear explanation. The problem seems to be that you won't read anything we tell you.

Comment: i read that in google search much earlier than i come to stackOVERFLOW. And i repeatedly said this is not helping. I still not get an actual guru who can solve this silly problem, which is bigger for me.

Comment: Then why don't you show us your attempt at using a prepared statement, so that we can show you where it's wrong?

Comment: `and i want to store date like this, 28/4/2013, into a database, so please somebody help me`

No, you can't. What you can do however: store a _string_ with the given format, or store the date, and when querying, _convert it_ to the given format. MySQL (as other DBs too) does not give a flying f... flip about the textual, human readable format of a date - it uses a binary format to store it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be something, like the following. Better list the column names, for future changes to the table, and for readability. A `(` got lost in your code. Using a prepared statement escapes strings and prevents SQL injection. For dates, integers and such it is also beneficial.

```
java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(d).getTime());

PreparedStatement stmt = db.conn.createPreparedStatement(); 
String sql = "INSERT INTO diag.current (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement stmt = db.conn.createPreparedStatement();`
stmt.setString(1, col1);
stmt.setString(2, col2);
stmt.setDate(3, date);
stmt.setString(4, col4);
stmt.executeUpdate();
stmt.close();
```

I have edited my program using your help as shown below:

```
java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(SimpleDateFormatter("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(d).getTime());
PreparedStatement stmt = db.conn.prepareStatement(); 
String sql = "INSERT INTO diag.current (name, patientID, address, sex, phone, vip, email, purpose, history, tests, doc, charges, status, dob, nextapp) " +     
"VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";    
PreparedStatement stmt = db.conn.createPreparedStatement(); 
stmt.setString(1, name);
stmt.setString(2, id);
stmt.setString(3, add);
stmt.setString(4, sex);
stmt.setString(5, ph);
stmt.setString(6, vip);
stmt.setString(7, mail);
stmt.setString(8, pur);
stmt.setString(9, phis);
stmt.setString(10, tests);
stmt.setString(11, dc);
stmt.setInt(12, total);
stmt.setString(13, status);
stmt.setDate(14, date);
stmt.setDate(15, date);
stmt.executeUpdate();
stmt.close();
```

Q: But `SimpleDateFormatter` and `createPreparedStatement` is not supporting, which import I should use?

A: Typos, should have been

```
java.text.SimpleDateFormat
con.prepareStatement
```

Comment: setDate() accepts a java.sql.Date, not a java.util.Date. Almost +1.

Comment: this program doesn't work if you change the format to dd/MM/yyyy, because SQL only accepts yyyy/MM/dd. I think i made it clear what the real problem is.

Comment: @sudipta.dey: The format is only used to transform a user-provided string into a Date object. After that, the Date object is passed to the JDBC driver, which does the right thing. The date format is irrelevant. Trust the people who answer, are (almost) upvoted, and have a good reputation, instead of not even testing their solution.

Comment: true this doesn't address the date format issue but it's still a much better way to do the insert. You would be wise to listen to the advice. (post has now been edited to parse the date too)

Comment: @sudipta.dey an understandable mistake: under the hood of a prepared statement happens more than a substitution of `?` with `toString()`. In fact the SQL engine could have its own prepared statement, where the java driver just passes a long (secs since 1970) for a date or so.

Comment: Now that's the solution i want, other than words, thanks a lot Mr.@JoopEggen and Mr.@JBNIzet. You people really don't know what have you done, i was stuct here for 7 days, and heard lots of words, and like others i also got irritated. No thanks alot again. Love you both...

Answer (score 0):

From the MySQL Manual - [11.3.1. The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html)

> The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.
>
> The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.
>
> The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.
>
> MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. (This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME.) By default, the current time zone for each connection is the server's time.
>
> MySQL permits a “relaxed” format for values specified as strings, in which any punctuation character may be used as the delimiter between date parts or time parts.  For example YYYY/MM/DD is acceptable as a DATE.

So it appears that you have to create a text date in YYYY-MM-DD format to insert a date into MySQL.  When you retrieve a DATE field, you get YYY-MM-DD.

The PreparedStatement is supposed to do this conversion for you from a java.sql.Date when you use the setDate method.

Answer (score 0):

```
dateChooserDialog1.showDialog(this.getFrame());
Calendar d=dateChooserDialog1.getSelectedDate();

SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MM-YYYY");
String s=d.toString();
String dd=s;
String mm=s;
String yyyy=s;
int i=dd.lastIndexOf("DAY_OF_MONTH");
dd=dd.substring(i+13,i+16);
dd=dd.substring(0,dd.lastIndexOf(","));

int j=mm.indexOf("MONTH");
mm=mm.substring(j+6,j+9);
mm=mm.substring(0,mm.lastIndexOf(","));
j=Integer.parseInt(mm);
mm=String.valueOf(j+1);

int z=yyyy.indexOf("YEAR");
yyyy=yyyy.substring(z+5,z+10);
yyyy=yyyy.substring(0,yyyy.lastIndexOf(","));

//s.substring(busyIconIndex, busyIconIndex);

String dob=dd+"/"+mm+"/"+yyyy;
DateField.setText(dd+"/"+mm+"/"+yyyy);
```