# What is the standard way to keep timestamp in Java and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

Should I handle timestamp as String in java or as long? How to convert timestamps from Java to MySQL? Is there any standard pattern followed?

Comment: use
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808875/to-store-a-date-in-mysql-as-dd-mm-yyyy-format-through-netbeans-but-mysql-genera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to persist a `java.util.Date` into a database in Java, you will have to convert it to `java.sql.Date`. The fortunate thing about JDBC SQL Date is that it's a subclass of Java Date.

Therefore, to create a java.sql.Date from java.util.Date, you will have to do this:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date myDate = formatter.parse(date);
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(myDate.getTime());

db.insert_date(sqlDate);
```

Make sure that db.insert_date accepts only `java.sql.Date`.

also read about [java.util.Date vs java.sql.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305973/java-util-date-vs-java-sql-date)

Answer (score 0):

*Should I handle timestamp as String in java or as long?* you should not because timestamp class is already present in [sql package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html)

*How to convert timestamps from Java to MySQL?* use [setTimestamp()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp%28int,%20java.sql.Timestamp%29) and for example see this  [example](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-insert-timestamp-value-in-preparedstatement/)

Answer (score 0):

As such no standard pattern is followed. There is a method called **setTimestamp** available in **PreparedStatement**. You can use it to set timestamp values. More info is available at - [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp(int, java.sql.Timestamp)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp%28int,%20java.sql.Timestamp%29) and http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-timestamp-example-current-time-now